# show my java applet in HTML

Tags: java, html, applet

I'm having a trouble embedding my applet in my HTML code the error that appear to me myapplet.class not found in fact that myapplet.class on the same file of the HTML page.can any one figure the problem?
here is my applet code

```
package applet;

import java.awt.TextArea;
import javax.swing.JApplet;

/**
 *
 * @author Islam
 */
public class myapplet extends JApplet {

    /**
     * Initialization method that will be called after the applet is loaded
     * into the browser.
     */
    TextArea tx;
    public void init() {
        // TODO start asynchronous download of heavy resources
        tx=new TextArea();
        tx.setSize(100, 200);
        add(tx);
    }

    // TODO overwrite start(), stop() and destroy() methods

}
```

and here is my html code

```
<html>
<div class="qtext">
  <?php echo $questiontext; ?>
</div>

<div class="ablock clearfix">
  <div class="prompt">
    <?php echo $stranswer; ?>
  </div>
  <h1>Islam Nosser</h1>
  <applet ALIGN="CENTER" CODE="myapplet.class" WIDTH="800" HEIGHT="500"></applet>
  <br />
  <?php if ($feedback) { ?>
    <div class="feedback">
      <?php echo $feedback; ?>
    </div>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php $this->print_question_submit_buttons($question, $state, $cmoptions, $options); ?>
</div>
</html>
```

but still the applet doesn't appear and with [that alarm myapplet.class not found

Comment: We can't help with so little information.

Comment: I've had edited my question sorry for being misleading

Comment: @closers: the question has been edited now; maybe it should not be closed

Answer (score 2):

> *myapplet.class not found*

That's pretty self explaining. That file cannot be found. Let's look how you declared the applet.

```xml
<applet code="myapplet.class" ...>
```

So, it expects that the class file doesn't have a `package` declaration and that it is in the same folder as the PHP file containing that HTML code line. Fix it accordingly.

Comment: actually both the HTML file and the myapplet.class are on the same folder.

Comment: I overlooked that you declared a `package`. So you should remove it or to put it in a folder conform the package name and then reference it by `code="applet.myapplet"`.

Comment: sorry but I can't figure your point, did you mean that I must put the html file with myapplet.class in a folder with same name of package??

Comment: Remove `package applet;` from your applet and recompile the class. It should then work the way as you want. Or if you want to keep the package (very reasonable :) ) then you should ensure that you've compiled it from the package root in the classpath (i.e. you should be sitting in the folder which has `/applet` as child folder and then execute javac) and provide put the class in `/applet/myapplet.class` and reference it as `code="applet.myapplet"`.